# getting gtkimage width and height

Tags: gtk

How can i get the GtkImage width and height after reading from  a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the size of the actual image, you need to go through the [GdkPixbuf](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk-pixbuf/unstable//gdk-pixbuf-gdk-pixbuf.html#GdkPixbuf) API:

```
const GdkPixbuf *pb = gtk_image_get_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(image));

printf("image is %ux%u pixels\n", gdk_pixbuf_get_width(pb),
                                  gdk_pixbuf_get_height(pb));
```

Note that this size is not the same as the size of the GtkImage widget that shows the image, since the widget can be given a different size by GTK+'s layout engine.

Answer (score 2):

`GtkImage` is a subclass of `GtkWidget`.  You should be able to use `gtk_widget_get_allocation`, and use the `height` and `width` fields of the `GtkAllocation *` that it returns.